# Web Api Projects on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, rider

I am new to using Mac. I want to try running my projects in the mac by cloning from Github. I installed Visual Studio for Mac and try to run Projects, MVC projects run good but Web API projects are not running.

I tried to add a new project and don't see Web API project but found Core Web API Project. Does it mean Mac OS only supports Core Web API?

I tried running in Jet Brains Rider too. I am having the same issue.

As I am new to the Mac, appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: When you target multi platform, you need to use .Netcore rather than .Net framework

Comment: @Kalyan So we cannot run already developed web api(not core) projects in Mac ?

Comment: No. It's not possible to use it directly. You have to upgrade your framework api to core api. take look at this url: https://stackify.com/asp-net-core-web-api-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .NET Core SDK? If not this URL https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos helped you.

Comment: I installed core sdk before. Thanks

Comment: @Chatra have you any errors when you run api project?